# Radio buttons stop and start working depending on where they are on page

Tags: excel, radio-button, activex

I'm having a strange problem.

I have 3 worksheets that have 2 sets of radio buttons at the bottom of each sheet. On the first sheet, these radio buttons work fine. On the 2nd and 3rd sheet, the radio buttons on the bottom-middle of the page work, but the ones on the bottom-left side of the page do not. When I hover over them the cursor changes appropriately, but when I click on them they just flicker and the button does not fill in.

When I tried remaking the buttons, I found that if the buttons are situated in the middle or right side of the sheet, they work fine, but if I move them over to the left side of the sheet they stop working. It does not seem to be any particular cell line that breaks them (it appears that they consistently stop working in the middle of the M column). When I move them back to the right side of the page, they work again. If I have one button from a particular GroupName filled and move it over to the left, it remains filled and if I click on different button from the GroupName that is situated on the right, the button on the right fills in properly and the button on the left clears properly...I just can't click the button on the left to refill it.

I've tried copying the radio buttons directly from the first sheet (whose buttons are working properly), but that didn't work. I have also copied the formats from the first sheet onto the second sheet, thinking maybe the format of the cells was breaking the radio buttons in some way, but that didn't work either.

Has anyone heard of anything like this happening?

EDIT: I tried putting in a different ActiveX Control (a text box) and it too stops working when it is moved to the left side of the page.

Comment: Could you have a transparent locked shape in front of that particular area? Strange issue so I'm thinking obscure solutions ;p

Comment: I appreciate the creativity! But it looks like I don't have a transparent shape in the way.

I added another page to the worksheet and tried copying everything over onto that one. The new page exhibited the same problem, not working on the left side. I moved the buttons back over to where they originally were on the other page and saw no difference in functionality (still not working left of row M). When I moved them BACK over to the left side of the new page, they worked! For about 5 seconds, before stopping again. So odd!

Do you know of anywhere I can upload the file so others can view it?

Comment: Huh! It looks like whenever I reopen the document, the radio buttons work for a few seconds (I can click between them 2-4 times) but then they abruptly stop working again. Is there some part of excel that loads up a bit slowly that could be interfering?

Comment: Check in VBA editor if Personal.XLAM has any code affecting your document. Also see if you can replicate the behavior on someone else's computer to confirm if maybe it is specific to your local computer.

Comment: I finally got around to checking the document on other computers - the problem persists! The VBA editor for this workbook does not appear to have Personal.XLAM readily visible. Is that odd?

I ended up rearranging the document so I could just have all my radio buttons on the right side so this is kind of a nonissue now, but it is still mysterious!